# All probability densities are Gibbs form.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics, gibbs-measure

In this https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2018/03/09/tutorial-on-large-deviation-principles/ blog post on Large Deviations the author says

> By the way, let me tell you a secret: all probability distributions are indeed Boltzmann–Gibbs measures.

What do they mean by this?

Comment: It just means that $f=  \exp(-V)$ where $V = -\log f$, see the comment section in your linked post